# copy and paste to table in a more efficient way

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have an excel file with 2 sheets:

1.INFO (huuuge table, around 10.000 rows)
2.ADD INFO

The second is where my issue is. Basically it has 2 functions, either filter (based on 2 different criteria) and search for info in the table and display it on that sheet or add a new row to the table. The macros i made work fine, but it seems weird to me that 1 minute is too long for it to complete the task:

```
Sub Search_in_table()

Dim header As Range


Sheets("ADD INFO").Select
Range("A13").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

If Worksheets("ADD INFO").[Item_to_search] = "Cust_ID" Then
    Sheets("INFO").Select
    Set header = [A1:Y1]
    With header
        .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Worksheets("INFO").[What_I_Want]
    End With

ElseIf Worksheets("ADD INFO").[Item_to_search] = "ASIN" Then
    Sheets("INFO").Select
    Set header = [A1:Y1]
    With header
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Worksheets("INFO").[What_I_Want]
    End With

End If

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Sheets("ADD INFO").Select
Worksheets("ADD INFO").[A13].PasteSpecial

Sheets("INFO").Select
header.Select
Selection.AutoFilter

Sheets("ADD INFO").Select

End Sub
```

And this is the one to add a new row:

```
Sub add_esc()

Sheets("ADD INFO").Select
Range("Y9:A9").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("INFO").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial

Sheets("ADD INFO").Select
Range("A9:Y9").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Is there a way to make them more efficient? Did i miss something? BTW, What_I_Want and Item_To_Search are just cells with names. An interesting fact is that during the writing of the code, i got very weird errors in things like "selection.paste", and that is why i was using a not common notation like "Worksheets("ADD INFO").[A13].PasteSpecial"

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend getting rid of "select" and "activate" wherever you can, should speed things up and ultimately avoid bugs. Are you able to just clear ALL cells on sheets("add info") for example? sheets("add info").cells.clear

As for the rest of the code: can't remember doing anything similiar but theory sounds OK... get rid of all those "selects" though, they just slow things down. Where you've got:

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Sheets("ADD INFO").Select
Worksheets("ADD INFO").[A13].PasteSpecial
```

Instead just use this (and for extra credit, instead of using Sheets() refer directly to the sheets codename:

```
wsInfo.autofilter.range.copy wsAddInfo.cells(13,1) ' i.e. row 13, column 1 (col A)
```

Not sure about the rest of your question re: add rows etc, but using method above maybe you just need to increment that copy destination row? Or use application.worksheetfunction.counta(range) to find the last used cell rather than "select" etc...

There's the possibility that your method might actually be slower than just iterating over each row manually and copying where condition's met? Might be worth a try. Something like:

```
for each rgCell in rgList
    if rgCell.offset(0,4) = stCrit1 _
        and rgcell.offset(0,8) = stCrit2  then
        rgcell.entirerow.copy wsAddInfo.cells(intDrawRow, intDrawCol)
        intDrawRow = intDrawRow + 1

    end if
next
```

And if all else fails, and i strongly recommend you get rid of all the "selects" in your code before doing this, use application.screenupdating = false at the start of your code, and application.screenupdating = true at the end of your code. Highly recommend error handling so that you set screenupdating back to true on errors too.

Cheers, Si